# How to Edit the Uploaded scripts in the HP Performance Centre?

Tags: loadrunner

I'm working on the LoadRunner Tool to perform a Performance Test of a Web Application developed in Sharepoint. I have recorded the scripts and tested the scripts.

I have uploaded the scripts in the Performance Centre for Load Testing. But, the issue is I have some parameters like URL which have to be changed before running the script in the Performance centre. How can I edit the parameter values in the performance centre. Do we have any options to edit the script in the performance centre itself or we have to download the script, edit it and then upload it again.

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Udhay.

Comment: Not really clear. Where are the URLs right now -- hardcoded in the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to edit scripts with in performance center. One thing you can do is sync the Vugen with performance center and open the script and edit it and save.

This option can be found in Tools menu in Load runner.

Answer (score 0):

You can also find out if you are running under the Controller or VuGen by using this code:

```
int function isVuGen()
{
    // Check if we are running under VuGen
    //
    // Returns
    //   0  = Under Controller
    //   1  = Under VuGen

    if (strcmp(lr_get_master_host_name(),"None") == 0) return = 1; // VuGen

    return 0; // Controller
}
```